# Meaning of "the lame and the blind"

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, yerushalayim-jerusalem, handicap-disabled-impair, abraham

I read somewhere recently that the "the lame and the blind" in 2 Samuel 5 is a reference to the patriachs, and that Abraham had made an agreement with the Philistines not to lay claim to Jerusalem in exchange for the cave where he buried Sarah: this agreement then becomes contentious when David turns his attention to Jerusalem.

Is this correct?

Comment: BTW:The original says "הַעִוְרִים וְהַפִּסְחִים" - "the blind and the lame"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say is similar - somewhat - to what the [Ralbag explains there](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01433.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2).

He says it refers to the covenant that Abraham made with Abimelech not to fight with each other:

- The blind refers to Isaac who- towards the end of his life - lost his sight.
- The lame refers to Jacob who - after the fight with the angel - limped for a while.

> וַיֵּלֶךְ הַמֶּלֶךְ וַאֲנָשָׁיו יְרוּשָׁלִַם אֶל הַיְבֻסִי יוֹשֵׁב הָאָרֶץ וַיֹּאמֶר לְדָוִד לֵאמֹר לֹא תָבוֹא הֵנָּה כִּי אִם הֱסִירְךָ הַעִוְרִים וְהַפִּסְחִים לֵאמֹר לֹא יָבוֹא דָוִד הֵנָּה:‏
>
> **רלב"ג**  והנה היה היבוסי יושב בירושלים ולא יכול דוד להוציאם משם בעבור ש**בועת אברהם לאבימלך** שהיתה כתובה בצלמים אשר שם שהם עורים ופסחים כי עינים להם ולא יראו רגלים ולא יהלכו ואפשר שהיו הצלמים ההם בצורת עִור ופִּסח **העור להורות על ברית יצחק** שבסוף ימיו כהו עיניו מראות **והפסח בעבור יעקב שהיה צולע על יריכו** ועשו זה להורות שכבר נשתלש להם זה הברית עם האבות בכללם ולזאת הסבה אמר היבוסי לדוד לא תבא הנה אם לא הסירות תחלה העורים והפסחים שבהם זכירת זה הברית כאילו יאמר לא יבא דוד הנה כי לא יוכל להסיר אלו הצלמים שבהם זכירת זה הברית‏

Comment: Thank you for that link: I found some more information here in this similar question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/david-and-jerusalem

Comment: The other explanation of the Ralbag there is that they're some type of robot, powered by water; that's why whoever chose to fight them needed to bust the water pipes. Specifically lame and blind, because the sticks on the robots that they would use to whack intruders resembled walking sticks.